# Error when installing the 'graphics' package (but not others) in R

Tags: r

I am a starter in R and new to StackOverflow and this is the first time I raise a question, I hope i'm following all the rules...

Anyway. I got R (3.5.0 version) and R-Studio on my laptop with Win 10 Home installed (under the same parent folder 'D:\') and reset the temporary file directory to a folder in D:\ so that the Chinese in C:\Users\中文\documents (which is the default place for tempo files) doesn't affect the connection btw R-studio and R (I was told any relevant directory has to be in English to make R-Studio work).

The problem is, I cannot install the 'graphics' package when I run

```
install.packages('graphics')
```

The resulting error says something like this:

```
>Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
>Restarting R session...
>Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
>Error saving session (options): R code execution error
>WARNING: Forcing suspend of process in spite of all session data not being fully saved.
```

It's quite weird since the 'graphics' package is pretty basic and as a matter of fact I haven't found anyone reporting such errors on the internet.

**It also bothers me that other packages like 'forecast' and 'XML' can be successfully installed without any error report.**

I've looked at some similar questions on StackOverflow, having error reports with "*Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection*", but they all seem to have something else to complete the sentence. In my case it just stops the error description with "*cannot open the connection*". Also I couldn't find people having similar problems with "*Error saving session (options): R code execution error*".

I do realize that this is quite unusual. I can't even find the proper tags other than r for this question. Although it seems that no one has trouble with the 'graphics', this problem is really bothering me and I hope someone can give possible solutions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like you already have it installed. Do you get an error when you write `library(graphics)`

Comment: gee... I do have it already... But why don't I need to write the code on the other laptop to use the "plot" function? is it because I never deleted the R.history file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have a session that doesn't recognize the `plot` function? If so, try doing `library(graphics)` first?

Comment: (don't even know what session means but) Yes. I extracted a dataframe from a website (with the function in XML package) and tried to plot one column, but it reported something which I don't remember now. To make sure that it was not my misuse of the 'plot' function, I wrote "?plot" and there wasn't any information i expected shown in the side box. Instead it said something like I didn't have it. This is why i ran 'install.packages('graphics')' because i thought i didn't have it on the newly installed R

Comment: Okay, try it again with `library(graphics)` first. My only guess is that for some reason that package is not loading at startup.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! This problem kept me for a whole day. I was quite afraid to ask on StackOverflow some hours ago because I could sense there must be something stupidly wrong.